# how to display mapplic routes svg (minimap) within the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I am using jQuery mapplic plugin, calling in div element in the following way:

```
<div><section><div id="mapplic" class="mapplic-routes"></section></div>
```

After selecting from and to and go Icon in the routes svg is zooming and not displaying within the fixed position. The image is big in size and zooming to top within the browser.

How do I display mapplic svg image in a fixed position?

I tried with position property and tried with div properties.